# What screenshot tools are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I have noticed that many people use images in their *Ask Ubuntu* answers. What software are people using?

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate action. The other question is more general, not only screenshots releated. And this one is also more specific to AskUbuntu with question regarding how to publish them. Which is not covered in the other question.

Comment: for questions specific to AskUbuntu (Like where to host and upload images) please ask on [AskUbuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com)

Comment: @Marco, can you move it to the Meta? Or is it better to close it here and reopen it there?

Comment: The question was modified to make it acceptable for general use here. I'll leave it for @RunningUtes (or another user) to ask the Meta

Comment: You may also be interested in this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/3578/667

Comment: You can use Ksnapshot. It works well in Unuty. Search for it in Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: This question is from 2010. The accepted answer (Shutter) is no longer a good choice in 2018, the last release of Shutter was 2014. I suggest looking at alternative answers below! (Such as Flameshot, similar features, smaller footprint, new+active codebase)

Comment: Use Firefox and right click on the screen, then choose "Take Screenshot", then choose "Save full screen", then choose to download the image and it will be in your Downloads folder as a PNG file. This page won't let me add an answer so I can't add a real answer with images :/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Update:**
As of Jan 2022, I do see updates and fixes being released for Shutter so the below update I do not think is still apt. For e.g. they just pushed a release 0.99.2 on Oct 24, 2021.

**Update:**
As of Aug 2018, Shutter project [hasn't had a release or security fix since 2014](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/source-code/). Many key [libraries are depreciated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/1765726), it may not exist [beyond Ubuntu 18.04](https://youtu.be/RPkywfQ8BRA). Consider a newer maintained alternative, such as one of the projects listed below. Know of something new and missing?  Add it!

---

I am using [**Shutter**](http://shutter-project.org/) [image: Download Shutter].

If you don't find it, you can check the [detailed installation instructions](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/ppa-installation-guide/) which will give you a PPA for it.

It's a really handy screen capture application with easy to use plug-ins to give a nice touch to your screenshot and as many other to easily share the files.

It offers in-house image editing and special effects (via plug-ins) to enhance the quality of your screenshot. You can access this options via the menu (1), or the toolbar (2).

[image]
*The effects here are all done with Shutter (Plug-in `Reflexion` and Edit `auto-increment shape`).*

And then to publish them, I just right click in Shutter and choose Export (3). Then I publish it via Ubuntu One. I go to the directory where I published the file, right click on it and select `Copy Ubuntu One public URL`.

Finally here when I comment, I click on `img` in the small tool bar and select `From the web` and paste the link that was copied in the previous step.

It's easy and fully integrated.

For those on 10.04, check that you have [all shutter dependencies](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/dependencies/). As you might miss some of the plug-ins. For user on Ubuntu 10.10, this should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Huygens.  This is great.  I use Gnome Screenshot right now.  I was also interested in options for taking screenshot besides using them in AskUbuntu.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I was just browsing though the Meta questions to see how you do for the APT links. I would also be interested for the style of the keyboard shortcuts. I did not find yet the question, keeping on searching.

Comment: @Huygens Still working on that - in the mean time it's hard-coding them :P

Comment: Thanks again Marco, I got a bit into trouble with this merge conflict ;-)

Comment: Shutter OWNS. Best screenshot utility ever. Upload to FTP? Send straight to flickr? Customized format / output ? Yeah, good enough for me.

Comment: Great tool, even with the dozens of dependencies it comes with on KDE. For the "Edit" feature (2), the package `libgoo-canvas-perl` must be installed. It took me a few minutes to figure out :o

Comment: Where has this been all my life? I've been living in the dark ages. To replace the regular print-screen option, [Shutter as default](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/set-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool/). From `man shutter`, `-f` full screen, `-a` active window, `-w` select window and `-s` selection.

Comment: My vote for Shutter.  Initially I thought it had way too many features, e.g. the image editing capability, but I found its use intuitive, it really nicely fits the my workflow for making and postprocessing screenshots.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155352/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-while-using-gnome

Comment: shutter absolutely sucks. Everytime I open it, it has to do some updates before its usable.

Comment: 2018 Shutter is outdated & crufty. Latest instructions for Shutter PPA are for Ubuntu 9.10. I suggest **Flameshot** Included in Ubuntu 18.04 repo :: https://askubuntu.com/a/1028370/139249

Comment: Hi @mikestewart this post is a community wiki. Feel free to change the answer. Perhaps keep the original answer (mark it as deprecated). I'm not doing much screenshots anymore, so I'm using whatever tool is available, which means Gnome Screenshot tool. I've seen that flameshot has already an entry, I've upvoted it.

Comment: 2019 Shutter homepage is Nginx 502 Bad Gateway :(

Answer (score 58):

## [GNOME Screenshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-screenshot) [image: Download Gnome Screenshot]

I find the GNOME screenshot tool to be the most effective of all. And it is installed by default!

My favorite is the use of shortcuts to quickly generate images. For example - <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> which takes the entire desktop and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> for the current focused window.

Furthermore the interface is extremely simple and powerful for such a small tool.

[image: Screenshot showing Gnome Screenshot interface]

It provides nearly the same functionality as the *Snipping Tool* in Windows via the *Select area to grab* option, but you can also make a screenshot of a window without the window frame and shadow.

Comment: This screenshot is exemplary of the reason I prefer not to use Gnome Screenshot – I have yet to figure out how to get it to include the window borders.

Comment: I believe it's an issue with Compiz - not sure though.

Comment: It is Compiz-related, yes.  I don't believe I've seen a screenshot tool that can include window borders in the presence of Compiz.

Comment: @Marius Shutter takes screenshot with Window Borders, in presence of Compiz

Comment: Incidentally Alt-PrintScreen is also used by the kernel (and is known as Magic SysRq).  Depending on your kernel version it may not be passed to the screenshot tool.

Comment: @Marius Gedminas: IIRC, Magic SysRq intercepts the *right-hand* Alt (usually labeled `Alt Gr`); left Alt+PrtScr is not intercepted by kernel.

Comment: @Piskvor: that's an interesting statement, but my experiments show it is not true.  Either of the Alt keys are treated as the magic SysRq here.

Comment: @Marius Gedminas: Hm, you are right - either Alt key + PrintScreen works as SysRq; however, you need to press SysRq + another key; pressing just Alt+PrintScreen invokes the screenshot tool in stock Ubuntu (at least since 9.04, up to and including 10.10; don't have Natty to test)

Comment: I remember when holding down Alt+SysRq to press one of those magic sysrq keys resulted in both the magic sysrq function _and_ 17 new screenshot dialogs appearing on my desktop due to auto-repeat.

Comment: I find it useful to set a shortcut for the area screenshot (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/170163/how-do-i-set-a-shortcut-to-screenshot-a-selected-area for more details)

Comment: the only feature it lacks , is that you can't draw anything on the shortcut. unlike the snipping tool in windows. that's very crucial for me

Comment: One reason why I don't use this tool is because it doesn't support transparency on rounded windows.

Answer (score 28):

Since [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29), including [16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_(Xenial_Xerus)), and [18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_(Bionic_Beaver)), simply press

- <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> to take a screenshot of the desktop,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> to take a screenshot of a window,
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> to take a screenshot of an area you select.

The screenshots will be saved to `~/Pictures`.

It is included in Official Documentation online help, *Ubuntu Stable: Tips & Tricks: **[Screenshots and Screencasts]**  [4](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html.en#screenshot).*

Comment: Its the most relevant answer I would say which does not requires an external software. Thanks for sharing the shortcut key!

Comment: I wish I could upvote 10 times)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get which key is `Prt Scrn` ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ced, on my keyboard its called PRTSC, and is shared with the END key. I have to hit a key labeled FN with the END key to 'press' the PRTSC button.

Answer (score 22):

### [Flameshot](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot)

A powerful open source screenshot and annotation tool for Linux, Flameshot has a varied set of editing tools available, including:

[image]

- Freehand drawing
- Lines
- Arrows
- Boxes
- Circles
- Highlighting
- Blur
- Save image, or upload to Cloud (Imgur), or copy to clipboard
- [Add Text](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot/issues/11#issuecomment-387029835) (Available in [version 0.6](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot/releases/tag/v0.6.0) )

You can customize the color, size and/or thickness of many of these image annotation tools.

#### Install

Flameshot is directly available in 18.04 from the `universe/graphics` repository. Usage info in [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/flameshot.1.html).

[Additional installation options](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot#installation), such as how to compile with latest features or installation on older/other distros, are available on project page. **Note:** Latest version installed from source has [cool features (not yet released)](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot/issues/314); but will be included in [version 0.6](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot/releases/tag/v0.6.0).

Comment: Came here to see if I could find flameshot listed! It looks beautiful and does what it's asked to. Amazing!

Comment: It's sooo much better than Shutter: no delay, upload, arrow tool, highlight tool…

Comment: Definitely a tool that changed my life! It super light and does almost anything you'd expect from such a tool. 10/10

Answer (score 19):

I recommend using the command line tool [`scrot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot) as it is easy to use and, unlike `import`, it supports transparency.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

To capture a screen area:

```
scrot -s /tmp/foo.png
```

Comment: `scrot` rocks! I had the problem that [ImageMagick's import command takes bad screenshot when running Compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/imagemagick/+bug/273976). `scrot` doesn't.

Comment: `supports transparency == the background (outside any windows caputured)` gets considered transparent?

Answer (score 14):

**[Screencloud](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screencloud) [image: Install screencloud]**

There is a new kid on the block of screenshot utilities: **[screencloud](http://screencloud.net/)**

[image]

It's a pretty cool tool, available in the Ubuntu Software Center (at least on Ubuntu 12.04).
[image: Install via the software center]

It has many nice features to easily share the screenshots via the Internet, hence its name.

- Upload the screenshot to screencloud. The link is automatically pasted to your clipboard;
- You can use an FTP or SFTP own server for this kind of sharing
- It's multi-platform.

Comment: What annotation features does it have?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I haven't used it for a long time. I can't remember it, sorry.

Comment: This apparently no longer exists.

Answer (score 10):

I use [GNOME Screenshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Screenshot), but for the sake of the reference and for all the old timers you can use [xwd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xwd) from the command line:

For a screenshot of your entire screen:

```
xwd -root | convert xwd:- out.png
```

Answer (score 10):

I use [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP). It has a nice tool which allows you to pause (to move it out of the way) and to select just a portion of the window. Usually I crop or edit a screenshot after taking it, so I want to be in GIMP anyway.

[image: GIMP 2.8.10 on Ubuntu]

Comment: This wouldn't be my first choice , but with the way Ubuntu handles the ALT key only fullscreen screenshots allow for scenarios like taking a screenshot of a drop down on a web page . GIMP's screenshot timeout feature makes that possible ...then you've got the rest of GIMP to modify the image if needed .

Answer (score 4):

[GNOME Screenshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Screenshot) does the job fine for me, but there is also [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imagemagick) for [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)-oriented folks:

```
import screenshot.png
import -window root screenshot.jpg
```

But, same as xwd, it will not work well with [Compiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz).

Comment: Funny story: almost every time you write a Python script,  forget to start it with `#!/usr/bin/python`, chmod +x and run it, you end up taking screenshots of random windows and writing them to files called 'os' and 'sys' in the current working directory, thanks to this.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Nanoshot](http://nanoshot.sourceforge.net/) - more simple than Shutter.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nanoshot/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nanoshot
```

Answer (score 4):

There is `ksnapshot` from KDE. Well, to me, this one *is* the winner because you can select whether you want a screenshot of a specific window, whether you want to have the mouse cursor visible and so on.

Moreover, it should not be forgotten that `gnome-screenshot` requires lots of "alien" components to be installed. So if you don't have said components installed, `gnome-screenshot` will bail out with the following ugly error message (under Ubuntu and its "remixes"):

```
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's built-in screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
```

Comment: ksnapshot also has a a very nice "Send To" feature that opens the captured screenshot directly in various applications such as GIMP or other image viewers. That doesn't seem to be present in most of the other programs listed here.

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler with the **[Compiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) plugin** called **screenshot**.

Open the **CompizConfig Setting Manager**, search for the **screenshot** plugin, and activate it.

To use it, hold down the windows key (super key), click and drag the screen that you want to grab, release, and KAZAM, your screenshot on the desktop.

For a video and tutorial, see Shawn Powers' LinuxJournal article *[Quick Compiz Screenshots](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/quick-compiz-screenshots?quicktabs_1=0)*.

Answer (score 2):

I use [5CM Uploader](http://img.5cm.ru/).
It has built-in editor and can upload screenshots to the image hosting.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:luza-mbox/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install 5up
```

Click on icon or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> for taking screenshot.

Comment: Is the app itself Russian too?

Comment: It has both russian and english UI.

Answer (score 1):

## [HotShots](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots/)

[Answer from SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/simple-program-to-edit-screenshots-add-texts-and-arrows-mark-stuff-on-linux/21077#21077). Note that, as of November 2016, HotShots hasn't been updated since 2014-Sep. The same can be said for Shutter, unfortunately.

---

Hotshots is a screenshot tool with some editing features. It is particularly suitable for writing documentation, but you can use it to highlight some details on a map image or what ever you want.

## [Features](http://thehive.xbee.net/index.php?module=pages&func=display&pageid=31#Current_Features)

Some important features:

- Free/libre software and *gratis*
- Can take screenshots: all screens, full screen, window, region, free hand region
- Can crop those screenshots or any image inside its editor
- Can add texts (where you will be able to choose the color)
- Can add arrows (where you will  be able to choose the color)
- Can mark stuff with rectangles / ellipses/ polygons/ curves (where you will be able to choose the color)
- Can use “system” shortcuts to take a screenshot.

## [Platform support](http://thehive.xbee.net/index.php?module=pages&func=display&pageid=31#Downloads)

- Linux (needs compilation such as on Slackware Linux; [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots/files/)) -- `libXfixes` and `libqxt` would be needed before compilation. Also, developer says that compiled packages are also available for Ubuntu and Arch Linux.
- Windows XP/Vista/7/8

## [Usage](http://thehive.xbee.net/index.php?module=pages&func=display&pageid=31#Usage)

HotShots is pretty simple to use (similar to **KolourPaint**, **MS Paint** or **GIMP**, if you used any of them), and you may refer to its [guide](http://thehive.xbee.net/index.php?module=pages&func=display&pageid=31#Usage) in case you need to know more.  As for the asked features, I have put them in an screenshot.

In the following screenshot, you would find:

- the interface of the HotShots
- zoom in on "Soft"
- custom text written below website's title
- a red colored arrow pointing to **Questions**
- a rectangle bordering first line of your question's body
- an image of a turtle added where question's stats were visible
- blurred the fourth requirement of your question's body
- made a free curve to make up for free hand requirement accompanied by a text box below it
- highlighted with yellow color a line of the body
- enclosed "Love this site?" by an ellipse
- encircled kittens roaming on my desktop

[image: IMG: HotShots features]

Answer (score 1):

[**Spectacle**](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/spectacle/)

KDE Framework 5 default screenshot capture utility is the Spectacle.

> Spectacle is a simple application for capturing desktop
> screenshots. It can capture images of the entire desktop, a single
> monitor, the currently active window, the window currently under the
> mouse, or a rectangular region of the screen. The images can then be
> printed, sent to other applications for manipulation, or quickly be
> saved as-is

> [image]

Spectacle - Development Information: https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/spectacle/development

Answer (score 0):

CopyQ linux clipboard manager tool has as well a printscreen functionality configurable in shortcuts, its instant, it freezes a screen without leaving any menues hiding. And it works also on desktopless environments, screen managers like xmonad.