# Do you have to deactivate or deinstall gnome-screenshot when using shutter?

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot

In relation to this question: [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/screenshot-tools-for-ubuntu)

Is it advisable to deinstall or deactivate gnome-screenshot when installing and using shutter? Or doesn't it make any difference (e.g. is there two daemons running now?)?

Activating shutter works perfectly, I'm just wondering whether the system gets bloated when installing a second tool to override the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tools aren't actually daemons running - but rather only run when executed or launched. It would be similar to having both OpenOffice and gEdit installed on a computer. Though they both serve the same function they won't collide with eachother.

You should be fine and safe to have both tools installed side-by-side

Comment: thx so much! Sry read you're answer second - so I change my mind and leave them both untouched! cya

Answer (score 1):

No not at all (unless your system has very little memory). Like [Marco said in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6595/do-you-have-to-deactivate-or-deinstall-gnome-screenshot-when-using-shutter/6597#6597) these are two different programs.

It's just like having Firefox and Google Chrome running at the same time. However if you don't think your ever going to use one of the programs again, I would uninstall it. No point in wasting space.

Comment: thx! So I will deinstall gnome-screenshot. Shutter is really cool imho. I won't use two different tools for shooting my screen :-), cya