# What snapshot software do you recommend?

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)

Hi,

is there a snapshot software for Ubuntu? Something like SnagIt?

The idea is many times I have to take the snapshot and edit the image to crop to my region of interest, SnagIt does that automatically and very nicely.

Another feature is to take a snapshot of text (that can't be otherwise copied - like text in a photo) and then parse it into actual text document using an OCR technology.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) ([Click to Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/shutter))

> Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.

[image]

Comment: shutter looks pretty much what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Shutter is def. the closest to snagit.

Answer (score 1):

For those one-off screenshots, Shutter might be a overkill. You can use xfce-screenshot for those purposes. Its very simple, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with snagit, but have you tried Shuttler? as far I know it's the most complete screen shot tool available for Linux.

Comment: Shutter or Shuttler?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, shutter is a very powerful utiity. It let you edits, run predefined plugins on it for 3d reflection and like effects and 2click upload to image hosting site for easy sharing. You won't need anything else, I am sure. :)

Comment: It can also take screenshots of full web pages by URL & a recent update also let you resize the window, take a screenshot and then resize it back to the original size, good for bloggers.