# Ubuntu screenshot program

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)

In windows 7 I had an easy to use "cut tool for screenshots", this one:

[image]

For Ubuntu I've found Shutter, but it isn't as easy and comfortable to use as the one I had in Windows 7.

Are any applications in Ubuntu 11.10 like these?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Firstly, this site works best if you ask one question at the time so I suggest you split it in two. Secondly, it would be easier to recommend a program for you if you described what features you're after.

Comment: Thanks,for the screenshots I only would like to cut a part of the screen and copy it to gimp, paint, whatever... The screenlets are cool...btw, is there any way to make my google calendar appear in my desktop?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you don't like Shutter. Shutter can replace all of the functions of snipping tool other than free form screenshots. Have you tried the quicklists of Shutter? They provide you a quick way to take screenshots.
Install Shutter either from the software center or through the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

[image]

Regarding the sticky notes, you can try Screenlets as mentioned in one of the other answers. To install screenlets, either search for Screenlets in the software center or run this command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

Search for Screenlets in the Dash and open the Screenlets manager. Click on Lipik and there, you have your sticky notes!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the screebshot tool, you might need to tell what exactly you are looking for. 
Are you aware that you can press Alt+Print to make a screenshot of only the currently focused application?

As for the notes application, you might want to look into [the screenlets notes](http://screenlets.org/index.php/Home). They seem to be similar as to what you have in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks,for the screenshots I only would like to cut  a part of the screen and copy it to gimp, paint, whatever...

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the screen shot with the Screenshot utility.
2. Save it to a location.
3. Open it with Shotwell photo manager.
4. Choose the option to edit it.
5. Crop it accordingly and save it.

Hope it may help.

Comment: You can also do this with GIMP easily by loading the screenshot of your whole screen in there, selecting the Crop tool, highlighting the portion you want to keep and pressing Enter. GIMP will get rid of everything outside the selection and you can re-save the picture as just the part you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Selective screenshot

1. In Accessories there's a Take Screenshot program with an option called "Select area to grab". Or if in Unity access it by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>, typing "Screenshot" or "Take", then opening Take Screenshot and choosing this option.
2. Using the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key, you can take a screenshot of the whole desktop. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> you can take a screenshot of only the active window, but in Keyboard Shortcuts under System Settings change or make a new one to do this while also asking how you want to have it. In that case, the command you need to put into the shortcut (new or existing) is `gnome-screenshot --interactive`.
3. Or you can make a shortcut on the desktop or launcher by dragging to there that program's icon.

## Notes

I would use that one which saves to the cloud. You can try:

1. Firefox with the Google Notebook addon.
2. Chromium browser with some plugin like Scratchpad or TaskFore plugin for Gmail.
3. Tomboy notes, which can be synced with [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-notes-sync/).

Comment: Also, can you provide links to the browser extensions you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to run those programs in Ubuntu using Wine (it is a software to run Windows programs under other OS). To install Wine, open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install wine`. Then just install the app you want double clicking the .exe file.

Comment: Thanks,for the screenshots I only would like to cut a part of the screen and copy it to gimp, paint, whatever...

The screenlets are cool...btw, is there any way to make my google calendar appear in my desktop?

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? By google calendar you mean the gadget?