# How to take a screenshot?

Tags: screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)

I have tried using ksnapshot and the only thing that does is take a screenshot behind the terminal and I have tried using Take Vector Screenshot.  Vector Screenshot does nothing and I'm lost. Please someone help me.

Comment: Have you tried screenshot?

Comment: Press the `PRINT SCREEN` key.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't there a 'PrtSc' button on the keyboard? it works perfectly and plus it lets you choose where you wish to save the pic and rename the pic directly so literally there is no need for a additional software for taking a screenshot.

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Try **Screenshot**. It comes with more advanced option than the Print Screen button. You can find it by searching "Screenshot" in the Dash.

---

Another more detailed Screenshot tool
**Shutter**
It has a plugin support and some image filters

#### Install it by ppa

> You can add a PPA to your system with the following procedure.
> Open a terminal and enter:
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa`
> Now, as a one-off, you should tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA you just added:
> `sudo apt-get update`
> Install Shutter
> `sudo apt-get install shutter`

Comment: Gnome screenshot is already installed in Ubuntu and is what you use when you press the PrtScr key, in the dash just type Screenshot to open it

Comment: @UriHerrera i gave that because i thought he might have removed it before or it wasn't on his system.

Answer (score 1):

Try Shutter. It has many options for taking screenshots.

`sudo apt-get install shutter`