# How do I set a shortcut to screenshot a selected area?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, screenshot

In gnome's screen shot program, the quick keys <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> captures the entire screen and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> captures the active window. Is there a way to script or set up the third capture option of a selected area?

Update: I don't seem to have this key already mapped...
[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: in 16.04 There is already a short cut of shift-print

Comment: This question was for 12.04. (It was a tag)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

1. Open **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts**
2. Select **Custom Shortcuts**(you can go to **Screenshot**-s too and it will work)
3. Click <kbd>+</kbd>
4. Fill fields

   - **Name** to `Take a screenshot of area`
   - **Command** to `gnome-screenshot -a` or `shutter -s`(if u prefer shutter)
5. Click **OK**
6. Double-click on what you make and set shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>

— And that's all ... ;)

---

[image: making command]

---

[image: settings shortcut]

Comment: How should I do this on Lubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: open **Sistem Settings** -> **Keyboard settings** and follow steps @Halkinn, or go to chat and say what you can't get

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has this shortcut built in out of the box now as per the answer below.

Comment: In Linux Mint, it's `Preferences -> KeyboardShortcuts`, and the command you need is `mate-screenshot -a`

Comment: Been a long time but theres a shortcut for this in Ubuntu 14.04 its 'ctrl+shift+prntscrn' hope this helps.

Comment: `gnome-screenshot -a -c` to send the screenshot to clipboard. After doing that, I tried `import gtk; gtk.clipboard_get().wait_for_targets()` in Python and got `('TARGETS',
 'MULTIPLE',
 'image/tiff',
 'image/jpeg',
 'image/x-MS-bmp',
 'image/x-bmp',
 'image/bmp',
 'image/png',
 'SAVE_TARGETS',
 'TIMESTAMP')`, so it offers multiple formats to the application where you paste it. Trying it in Inkscape, then saving, it becomes an embedded PNG. Pasting it into Google Docs, then _Download as ... Web Page_, it also becomes a PNG. Pasting it into Gmail, sending then _Show Original_, also PNG

Comment: Do you provide any CLI solution to map the shortkey with this command?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like a CLI option maybe, too. When I hit the PrintScreen button to set the shortcut, it... just takes a screenshot. :)

Comment: Oh, if I Disable the original shortcut, then I can set the PrintScreen button to my own shortcut. This was for setting up `/usr/bin/flameshot gui` shortcut, so I can jazz those snips up.

Comment: If you want to show the ui instead, use ```gnome-screenshot -i```

Answer (score 133):

That shortcut is already built-in: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> :)

The full-list of screenshot keyboard shortcuts is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't seem to have that. Would you mind posting a screen shot of which command this is mapped to? I've included a screen shot of mine above in the update.

Comment: Found it: gnome-screenshot -a

Comment: that is only in ubuntu 12.04+, and @Richard i have posted answer

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Works for me too on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Just to report in, this still works in Ubuntu 16.04 :)

Comment: It is documented here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the file saved?

Comment: @israteneda In your Pictures folder (/home/yourname/Pictures)

Comment: Works in linux mint 19.3 too

Comment: This has stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04. :O

Comment: Ah, actually just pressing "prt scr" / print screen and not any shift will now allow you to snip it.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Print is my favorite (checked on 20.04)

Answer (score 6):

While to above answers worked for me in Ubuntu; after switching to **Lubuntu** I noticed that the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PrtScn</kbd> was no longer working.

The following procedure fixed it for me. Since in Lubuntu the program `scrot` is used, I found that I had to add the following to the `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<!-- Launch scrot with interactive select when Shift-Print is pressed -->
<keybind key="S-Print">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>scrot -s</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

After the change do not forget to issue: `openbox --reconfigure` to activate the updates.

See [the Lubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Gnome now includes a tool by default.

The previous <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> seem to no longer work for me. Not sure if that is a regression.

But just pressing <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> (Print screen) will bring up this UI, allowing you to snip:

[image]

Image courtesy [omg! ubuntu! Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: Screenshot Tour](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/ubuntu-22-04-lts-screenshot-tour)

Comment: perfect! This is useful.

Comment: Thanks! This needs to go to the top!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this command from terminal if you have a problem with shortcuts.

```
sleep 5 && gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

Now open the window you want to take screenshot from and select the area after 5 seconds after the command execution.

```
sleep 5
```

makes the terminal waits 5 seconds before executing the command so you can go to the window you want within this while

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

takes screenshot of an area and copy it to clipboard.

Comment: Copy to clipboard (`-c`) was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For **xubuntu** and **xfce** users:

Run `Keyboard` app from the launcher menu, go to `Application Shortcuts`, check current action for `Print`, if it's `xfce4-screenshooter -f`:

1. add a new action: `xfce4-screenshooter -r`
2. Set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> for it
3. Check
4. Enjoy

If it's not `xfce4-screenshooter` - check the current tool how to run it in the "region screenshot" mode

Comment: A suggestion to add this to the default xubuntu package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1812234

Answer (score 0):

To take screenshot from a selected area And copy to clipboard, just press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd>