# How to enable Asus Fliplock 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, touchscreen

How do I enable Asus Fliplock? The touchscreen works great, but it does not disable the keyboard and trackpad when i turn the screen over. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not any "built-in" support for Asus FLipLock. I have come up with a script that toggles those.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #toggle keyboard and touchpad 
    key_device=12
    key_property=138
    touch_device=13
    touch_property=138
    flipped_state=$(xinput list-props "$key_device" | awk"/\\($key_property\\)/{print 1 - \$NF}")
    xinput set-prop "$touch_device" "$touch_property" "$flipped_state"
    xinput set-prop "$key_device" "$key_property" "$flipped_state"
    #toggle onboard
    #dbus-send --type=method_call --est=org.onboard.Onboard/org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.ToggleVisible
```

I commented out the onboard touch keyboard, as I could not get this function to work, and there are other ways to configure your onscreen keyboard.

I created a launcher for this, and added to my panel. Now I can turn those on and off at will.

I used this to modify my arandr generated scripts to rotate touch input with the display:
[Touchscreen Input Doesn't Rotate: Lenovo Yoga 13 / Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405628/touchscreen-input-doesnt-rotate-lenovo-yoga-13-yoga-2-pro)