# Ubuntu 22.04 touch on rotated screen not working

Tags: wayland, touchscreen

I use an Orange Pi 5 with ubuntu 22.O4 (https://github.com/Joshua-Riek/ubuntu-rockchip) with Wayland activated

I have a webkiosk like application with a rotated screen of 90 degrees. I can rotate the screen in the Ubuntu UI correctly but the touch screen is not working correctly. It seems the touch is not rotated.

I have been able to get it working by disabling Wayland and using Xorg but this seriously impacts UI performance and I m thus looking for a solution with Wayland enabled.

Thanks

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/405643/1698042

Comment: dont think this applies to Wayland...