# Automate taking a screnshot and sending the image to Inkscape

Tags: screenshot, inkscape

I very frequently use Inkscape to take a screenshot of some application.

Doing it while doing other jobs is somewhat distracting because it requires to take the screenshot, open the software to process the image, add some notes (and highlights and arrows and so on).

It would really help this process to find a way of taking a screenshot and opening inkscape and sending the image to it in a single shot.

Since I'm a Linux newbie, i don't know how (and if) it can be done.

Comment: Please give your OS, version and other information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could script this with `scrot`, e.g.:

```
scrot 'Screenshot_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.png' -szb -e 'inkscape $f'
```

This would create a screenshot in your home directory and open it in Inkscape. To bind the command to a key follow the instructions in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/170460/81372).

Some further detail on the options used:

- `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`: This will expand to `<year>-<month>-<day>_<hour>-<minute>-<second>`
- `-sb`: Interactively select screenshot area / click on a window to capture it in its entirety
- `-z`: silent mode, don't beep
- `-e 'inkscape $f'`: open screenshot in Inkscape

---

If you only want to perform simple edits to your screenshots you might want to use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) instead. It's a fully featured screenshot capturing solution with  an inbuilt editor and image uploader.