# What's the terminal name of the "take a screenshot" app in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I want to make a kb shortcut to open the app like I do on windows 10 and so I need to put the name of the app for it to be opened in the terminal, but I can't seem to find the name of the app.

By screenshot app I mean the app that opens when I press the super key. By name I mean like I write nautilus on terminal to open it.

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: The name of the application is `gnome-screenshot`. It shows up in Desktop Search as "Take a screenshot." See `man gnome-screenshot` for the many shell options. Note that this application already has [convenient keybindings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170163/) on a stock Ubuntu install.

Comment: @user535733 this question probably is about 22.04, which does not come with gnome-screenshot.

Comment: There is already a shortcut key defined, i.e., PrtScn. That can be changed.

Comment: Thx guys, I didn't know it could be changed just like that. Now I am using super key + S, way better for my use.