# Using scrot to take screenshots continuously

Tags: scripts, screenshot, scrot-command

I'm new to using [scrot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/scrot). I know how to take screenshots by typing the code `scrot Image.jpg`. I want to take continuous screenshots without the use of typing the code everytime on the Terminal.

Is there a way to do so and if so, what should I do in order to do so?

Comment: What do you mean continuous screenshots? How many do you want to take them?

Comment: I just want to see if I could take more than one screenshot at a time using scrot with a delay of one minute

Comment: scrot doesn't have options for taking multiple screenshots. You need to use external loop for that

Comment: And what would that be??

Comment: I've written an answer. Check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrot *doesn't allow* taking multiple screenshots in batch. However, you can use bash (or any other languages') loop feature to achieve this.

Here is how I took 10 screenshots in files named `screenshot_n.png` (where `n` is the sequence number`) in delay of 1 seconds each.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do sleep 1; import -window root screenshot_$i.png; done
```

I used the `import` tool here. It came from imagemagick. You can use scrot in place of `import`. Change the `sleep 1` line to match your desired delay. Check [`import` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/import.1.html) for more details.

You can use it in bash-function also like this

```bash
function shot()
{
    for i in $(seq 1 $1); 
    do 
        sleep 1; 
        import -window root screenshot_$i.png; 
    done
}
```

Save it in `.bashrc` file. You can use it in bash with this syntax `shot n`, where `n` is the number of screenshot you need to take`

Here is another command that uses `scrot`. I used scrot's built-in delay feature instead of bash `sleep` command here. Check [scrot man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/scrot.1.html) for more details. You can use this in bash-function as before.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do scrot -d 1 screenshot_$i.png; done
```

---

You can check the following question to get suggestions for other screenshot taking tools from command line

> - [What is the terminal command to take a screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot)

Comment: Anwar, you can improve your answer if you make it into a bash function, and pass an integer , so that in `seq 1 $1` it can run from 1 to x number of screenshots. Also, please don't use backticks, use `$(seq 1 $1)` , it's far better for readability

Answer (score 1):

Would not be this good enough?

```
watch -n 5 "scrot peepshow.png" # snaps the screen every 5 seconds
```

or if you want to save the snapshots

```
watch -n 3 "scrot peepshow\$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).png"
```

"Off you go" with CTRL-C.