# How to make screenshot gallery from command line?

Tags: screenshot

I'm wondering if there is any command line tool to take clean and fast screenshot gallery of a video?

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot

Comment: @devav2 I mean screenshot gallery of a video, so I guess `scrot` would not be useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Once you edited your question I can see what you wish is to extract some frames from a video in order to be used like a gallery of the contents of such video file. So we're going to use the `ffmpeg` command in order to do this job.

First of all we need to install ffmpeg which can be done by dropping this in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Once installed, make sure you are in the right directory in the terminal and once you have found your video file in the results of the `ls` command, write this in the terminal:

`ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 0.5 -f image2 output_%05d.jpg`

This will extract a frame from every 2 seconds, which you can adjust if first we explain/understand the parameters of this command as follows:

1. `ffmpeg` = Is the program which will do the conversion/extraction.
2. `-i video.avi` = Indicates the "input" file, can be an absolute or relative path
3. `-r 0.5` = this indicates the framerate, which can be used to calculate how many frames are we going to use/skip in order to get the right
   number of frames we need from the video.
4. `-f image2` = ***a)*** `-f` "force format" ***b)*** [`image2`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) "Image file
   demuxer" (let's read it as: **force convert to image**)
5. `output_%05d.jpg` = it the filename's pattern which be used in order
   to drop images with sequential filenames with five trailing zeroes
   so they will be perfectly arranged in a list.

Give this a try and you may wish to read more about the ffmpeg command options by using the ffmpeg --help command in a terminal or in the proper documentation webpage at https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Good luck!

Comment: Well your command  takes very many photoshots and does not assemble them as I wished to make a `gallery`. A  much better command that I just found is this: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i in.mp4 -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,1000)),scale=320:240,tile=2x3" out.png`. What I miss in that is just to add title, filetype, resolution and size.

Answer (score 2):

[vcsi](https://github.com/amietn/vcsi) can do this. It is a command-line tool written in Python.

```
vcsi video.mkv -o output.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished by using the command line `mplayer`, install this as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

To generate screenshots *manually* while watching your video use the following syntax:

```
mplayer -vf screenshot file.mp4
```

While this running simply press the lower case 's' key to generate a screenshot. To generate multiple screen shots *automatically* simply press the upper case 'S' key and this will generate screenshots until you press 'S' again.

If you want a little more control of the output try something like the following:

```
mplayer -nosound -frames 5 -vo png:z=9 file.mp4
```

This will output the first 5 frames of the media file in high quality png format into the working directory. Similar screenshots can be taken by using jpeg, gif89a, targa and pnm as '-vo'.

**References:**

- [Top 10 Tricks and Tips for the svn MPlayer](http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/topten.html)

Comment: Well, I want a screenshot GALLERY, that is, the shots should be taken at even timing from the WHOLE video. How to do that using mplayer command?

Comment: @wbad Lose the 'frames 5` option I gave: `mplayer -nosound -vo png:z=9 file.mp4`

Comment: This one takes ages, as it passes through all frames.

Comment: @wbad My suspicion is that your answer will come from either FFmpeg or MPlayer with FFmpeg being the better choice...