# How to enable globe in Shutter in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: screenshot, shutter

I want enable globe in Shutter for taking screenshots of whole web pages.

[image: globe in Shutter]

For enabling globe I need install gnome-web-photo package. I use this command

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-web-photo
```

I get an error

```
E: Package 'gnome-web-photo' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the [official download webpage for gnome-web-photo for Ubuntu 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gnome-web-photo/download).
2. Select a mirror and download gnome-web-photo_0.10.6-1_amd64.deb
3. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains the gnome-web-photo_0.10.6-1_amd64.deb file that you downloaded.
4. Install gnome-web-photo with the following command.

   ```
    sudo apt install ./gnome-web-photo_0.10.6-1_amd64.deb
   ```

   This command automatically installs gnome-web-photo's dependencies along with the package.
5. You might need to restart shutter or reboot OS in order to see changes.

---

The shutter .deb package has been discontinued in Ubuntu 20.04. Shutter is still available as a snap package and can be installed by running `sudo snap install shutter`, but Shutter's grab a screenshot of the current window plus one of its menus feature no longer works in the Shutter snap package. Fortunately the default "Screenshot" app in Ubuntu 20.04 now has the features that Shutter used to have in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Also I was need to reboot Ubuntu.

Comment: I added `sudo reboot` to the command in step 4.

Comment: why would you add `sudo reboot` to a command someone is likely going to copy-paste without reading? could at least make it a separate bullet point

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `gnome-web-photo` has no package in 18.04, as you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gnome-web-photo). To capture and edit screenshots in firefox though you can use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/easyscreenshot/) web extension. For chromium you can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp).

Comment: I'll update my answer with a better extension (if I can find one) as soon as I'm able to, thanks for the heads up