# Take scrolling screenshot in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I want to take a scrolling screenshot of a page (**not a web page**, so browser extensions won't work, as in [Screenshot Tools to Capture Scrolling Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231757/screenshot-tools-to-capture-scrolling-windows)) that is too big for a normal screenshot.

In Windows I used to use [PicPick](https://picpick.app/) and [Sharex](https://getsharex.com/), but those do not work in Ubuntu. For normal screenshots in Ubuntu I use [FlameShot](https://flameshot.org/), but it does not have a scrolling screenshot feature.

So what app can I use in Ubuntu to take scrolling screenshots?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screenshot Tools to Capture Scrolling Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231757/screenshot-tools-to-capture-scrolling-windows)

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge to this day there is no the app that could take a scrolling screenshot on Ubuntu except webpages. On the Windows to do this I used [Screenpresso](https://www.screenpresso.com/) that could capture majority of the scrolling screenshots (terminals, mail clients, a code from an IDE, webpages and more).

I've checked 16 alternatives to the Screenpresso on the [alternativeto](https://alternativeto.net/software/screenpresso/?platform=linux) for Linux. I haven't found the app that handles scrolling screenshots on the Linux.

There are plans to introduce the feature in the screenshot tools in Linux, eg. [Knisp - feature request](https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip/issues/398)

Comment: Since Screenpresso is for Windows only, you should provide the steps for installing it in Linux, because maybe it's not possible to install it in Ubuntu, not even with Wine.

Comment: @karel Thank you for your advice but I'm not familiar with Wine soft. I've just wanted to indicate that there isn't exists a Linux-native app which could handle features such as scrolling screenshot. We could wait or create workarounds like you said.