# How can I get PDF viewer to display text?

Tags: pdf, text

When I open a PDF file, it doesn't display text.  Graphics show up.

How do I get the PDF viewer to display text?

Comment: Also, what is the actual name of the PDF Viewer you are using? Can you run it from a terminal? Any errors reported there may help diagnosis.

Comment: Open [this PDF form](http://ubuntuone.com/1RMukQiRrHIGr3zr4aFMVF) with your PDF viewer and [take a screen-shoot](http://askubuntu.com/q/6558/62483), then upload it to [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link it into your question. **NOTE:** You can know the name of your application in the *About* menu.

Answer (score 2):

> I erased my machine and re-installed 12.10. Right before I added all
>   the fonts I know and love, the PDF viewer works.
>
> AFTER... I add the fonts, it stops working. I can only guess that one
>   of the new fonts is overwriting a "core" font Ubuntu needs to make the
>   PDF viewer work.
>
> Anyone know how to restore that font?
>
> I could go through the 900 I install one at a time to see which one is
>   doing it, but that seems like it would take a while.

From: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12516767&postcount=13

> the phrase "core" font made me wonder if Ubuntu had such a thing... it
>   does.
>
> In /usr/share/fonts/truetype
>
> I add my own folder called "myfonts" with 900 .TTF files. When I
>   remove that, the PDF viewer works.... sooo.... I found a folder called
>   "ubuntu-font-family" and copied the contents of that folder to
>   "myfonts" folder overwriting my substitutions with the system
>   originals.
>
> That worked.
>
> The PDF viewer is working normally now. Thank you all.

From http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12516785&postcount=14

<sup>In other words, OP has the solution here:  [[SOLVED] PDF files show no text in 12.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117061)</sup>

Comment: I copy my fonts to `~/.fonts` and get no problem with overwriting core fonts.

Comment: I posted the answer purely because *I* got the impression that OP won't follow up. Who knows what fonts OP had :). So, one can't conclude that copying *any fonts* to ~/.fonts will cause a problem because it didn't for you (and possibly many other people) but did so for OP.

Comment: :D I just want to introduce an alternative for avoiding such problems but misunderstood! I just recommend to copy fonts to your home directory, not to the root one.

Answer (score 0):

How are you able to create a folder in the usr/share/fonts/truetype when it's disabled?

and is there a way to install multiple fonts instead of opening and installing them one at a time?

I only have one pdf file that doesn't show the text while it opens other pdf files with no problem.

Answer (score -2):

There are two choices you can make, one is to install Adobe Reader, the other is if you're using Chrome / Chromium, to make that the default .pdf reader.

Comment: 1: That may not address the central issue of why OP is **not** seeing text in the default PDF Viewer. 2: Chrome, not Chromium, comes with a PDF Viewer "built-in".