# Extra characters showing up when I type

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

I am using 12.04 LTS and ext+r9a char9act+er9s ar9e showing uap when I t+yape.  Also a lar9ge black r9ect+angle wit+h a cir9cle and bar9 symbol keeaps showing uap.  I am concer9ned t+his may be associat+ed wit+h an at+t+emapt+ t+o hack me (unusual act+ivit+y on a websit+e.  Any ideas?

Comment: When did this start happening, can you post picture of rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

Could be broken keyboard/hardware. I'd try swapping the keyboard first.
There is a possibility that this is a symptom of a keylogger. I definitively wouldn't type in any passwords until you're absolutely sure your system is clean, also be on the lookout for strange activity in the syslog (/var/log/syslog) and any of your online accounts.

Comment: T+his st+ar9t+ed haapapening ear9lier9 t+oday when I waqs using a websit+e.  I accessed somet+hing I t+hink I s[8hnouldn't+ have and t+hnen it+ st+ar9t+ed hnaapapeningb.  Do you know t+.hne key combinat+.ion t+.o apr9ess t+.o gbet+. a scr9eenshnot+.? t+.es[t+.

Comment: @roger To make a screenshoot press the `ImprPantPetSis` button. Look [What screenshot tools are available?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6558/62483)

Comment: The rectangle is not appearing anymore so I can't post a screenshot (I am using the mouse keyboard to type this.)

Comment: ow my yapeingb hnas number963s in i lik,e hnis.  est+. et+.

Comment: I tried a different keyboard but it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Could I have the wrong character encoding set?

Comment: I doubt that it's the character set... Did you try restarting?