# Taking screenshot saves a black image with the cursor only

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

Whenever I do a screenshot, it saves a black image with the cursor only. However, if I do a screenshot after an app or Unity freezes, it would save an image in the state when the app or Unity was frozen. I have an ATI Radeon HD 6290 graphics card which uses the proprietary FGLRX experimental beta driver, the other versions of the proprietary drivers (stable, post-release, FireGL) also do the same. Running on Ubuntu 12.04.2.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to tt1 (ctrl + alt + f1) and back to tt7 (ctrl + alt + f7), then take a screenshot. hat workarounds the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known `Compiz` bug: [gnome-screenshot produces black screenshot with only the mouse pointer visible](https://lists.launchpad.net/compiz/msg38019.html).

One fix mentioned on this [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=32801) is to disable Compiz desktop effects. You can disable desktop effects using `CompizConfig Settings Manager`. Which can be installed with Software Centre or using commandline:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You can also take a look at other screenshot tools hare: [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6558/37006)

Comment: I don't use Compiz, since I boot straight to Unity 2D and I have not logged in to the Unity + Compiz environment, but I might look over for that bug too.