# zscreen - real alternative for automated screen capture

Tags: screenshot

I know there's scrot for automated screen capture at every X seconds, but I need something like ZScreen which provides a GUI and simply by click Start and Stop, I can toggle between the process.

And also, I would like to set automatic folder creation for each day (just like ZScreen), so that every day, upon capturing the screen at every X second, the screenshot will be moved to the proper folder. I don't have time to do all this manually!!

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot options in ubuntu are as follows:

1. [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)
2. [Gnome Screenshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-screenshot)
3. [screencloud](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screencloud)
4. [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)
5. [5CM Uploader](http://img.5cm.ru/)
6. [kazam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/)

and off course scrot.

So take a look and choose which is suitable for you. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available) will help you

Comment: They are many others, like Kazam.

Comment: These apps don't have what I want...Never mind, I just developed an app for myself: https://github.com/Ropy/AutoShot/