# Ubuntu Gnome Facebook login error

Tags: gnome, facebook, online-accounts

I am not able to login into Facebook on online accounts of Gnome Ubuntu 13.10.

Always get this message (shown in screenshot)

> Your popup is too small to display this page.
>   Please enlarge it to proceed.

What should I do?

[image: screnshoot]

Comment: Could you take a [screenshoot](http://askubuntu.com/q/6558/62483)? Upload it to an image storage service (https://imgur.com for example) and link it here.

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: my screen resolution is 1024x768

Comment: Try with a higher resolution. Is it possible to enlarge the window?

Comment: I just ran into this problem too. There's no way to enlarge the window.

Comment: There is a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/1311899) that seems to be relevant to the issue - I got it on Ubuntu + Fedora...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just faced the same issue. The window is non-resizable and its size does not depend on the resolution.

While it is not possible to use <kbd>control</kbd> + scroll wheel or other usual key combinations to change the font size and make the login screen small enough to fit, you can use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to select the "Okay" button located underneath the semi-transparent warning text and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to validate the form. You must do that again on the following confirmation page.

If you don't touch anything on the page, the "Ok" button is actually already selected, so you should only have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> twice.

Hope that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> press your mouse over centre of the game launcher,
>   use scroll zoom out until youu can get the login screen

hope it works for facebook

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Although a link is always useful to add, it would be better to add the information here. Besides: links come and go, and might not be available in the future.

Comment: Jacob - Thanks. I wasn't thinking long-term. Your point is validated since the server in the link isn't responding right now.

Answer (score 0):

tab key to OK 
good luck !

or

press your mouse over centre of the game launcher,
use scroll zoom out until youu can get the login screen