# Mate, use gnome-screenshot instead of mate-screenshot

Tags: gnome, mate, screenshot

I am a big fan of Mate desktop. Simple and very functional.

But there one thing I'd address to the mate desktop: its screenshot utility is too poor.

The very single feature I miss there is being able to take a screenshot of only a part of the screen. It is apparently available with `gnome-screenshot` as from this post: [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)

Is there any way I could replace `mate-screenshot` to `gnome-screenshot`?

I tried `sudo apt-get install gnome-screenshot` but then if I try to launch it, I have

```
▶ gnome-screenshot
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
```

Besides, I really need the shortcuts (the whole point is to achieve it in two clicks), so even if I get it working, I'll also need this.

FYI, I was using shutter earlier, but removed it because it was lacking the desktop shortcuts and sometimes very buggy (need to hard shutdown the system).

Comment: Please see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316876&highlight=mate+screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `mate-screenshot` does have the utility you want, (see `man mate-screenshot`) so there's no need to install an extra package. In a terminal, you can use the `-a` flag

```
mate-screenshot -a
```

This turns the pointer into a cross-hair and you can click and drag to select the area you want to grab.

You can set a custom shortcut for it (for example <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>prt sc</kbd> like `gnome-screenshot`) in:

**System > Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard Shortcuts**

[image]

click the **+** Add button to add a custom one.

You may well find that using the command `mate-screenshot -a` in the keyboard shortcut does not work, in which case you need to modify the command to call bash and set DISPLAY... First check the variable in a terminal:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

and take note of the output. For me it's `:0.0`

Then use this command in the shortcut setting:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 mate-screenshot -a"
```

Replacing `:0.0` to match the output from `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: This solution does not work for me. the command works in a terminal but not as a shortcut. Any idea to help me ?

Comment: @sangorys did you try `echo $DISPLAY` and the second half of the answer?

Comment: Yes. The answer is :0 from the terminal and :0.0 from the shortcut. None of them are working ! :(

Comment: @sangorys So did you put in your shortcut assignment `bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 mate-screenshot -a"`?

Comment: yes indeed. And nothing works !

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the same issue by adding the `--interactive` option

```
gnome-screenshot --interactive
```

Comment: or `mate-screenshot --interactive`

Comment: Also fixes the same bug on Unity desktop after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04! Unfortunately, we cannot change the default screenshot commands, but we can still add custom shortcuts with --interactive.

Comment: Actually, one issue with this option is that is shows the config popup before taking the screenshot, even if you pass --window or --area, making the process much slower (you must press enter once to confirm the first popup). --clipboard also seems ignored, you need to manually click on the 2nd popup to copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

As @Zanna sais, mate-screenshot does have the availability of doing area screenshots.

But there is a well known bug (https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-utils/issues/37) which makes the command with this option fail.

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is to slighly delay the command:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
exec /usr/bin/mate-screenshot $@
```

within eg. `/usr/local/bin/mate-screenshot` and use it instead.

It changed my life, I keep using this feature now!

Comment: Looks too difficult. For which Ubuntu MATE version do you propose this solution? Why do not you want to use `mate-screenshot -i` instead?

Comment: Oh no ! You have no idea how `mate-screenshot -a` is much UX friendly than `-i`. Press `PrintScreen` make a square, and that's it, you have the cropped screenshot you need. What seems so difficult with this? I'm using the latest version of [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com) but the bug is hard to solve hence is here to stay.