# Recommendations for a simple screenshot annotation tool?

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot, image-processing

I am looking for a simple screenshot annotation tool with the following features:

- Crop
- Resize
- Blur
- Draw shapes and lines
- Add text

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/6570/158442?

Comment: Dear @muru, Shutter is a great solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than to use the screen capture tool `scrot` and open the resulting screenshot directly in `gimp`:

```
scrot -q 100 -e 'gimp $f'
```

You can set this particular commandline to a key, I illustrate here mapped to <kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image]

Or you can simply run it from the commandline with the glorious addition of a timer and delay:

```
scrot -d 10 -c -q 100 -e 'gimp $f'
```

The `gimp` should make short work of your image manipulation needs and there are many other `scrot` settings which you can tailor to your needs...

Comment: Dear @andrew.46, I appreciate your reply but GIMP is a too heavy tool for my taste.