# how to take screenshots using keyboard combo in Kubuntu 16.04.3?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

On OSX, I can easily take a picture of desktop using keyboard combinations (Shift-Option-3 or 4). And the images are automatically created in my desktop.

How do I simulate this on Kubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to assign keyboard shortcuts in Kubuntu? There's a nice GUI for it which is a little overwhelming but once you learn it, you're all set! Click on System Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts.

Comment: Askubuntu software recommendation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Taking a picture of the desktop using keyboard shortcut and the image is automatically saved to the user desktop**

Using Spectacle - KDE Framework 5 default screenshot capture utility:

```
$ spectacle --help
Usage: spectacle [options]
KDE Screenshot Utility

Options:
  -v, --version              Displays version information.
  -h, --help                 Displays this help.
  --author                   Show author information.
  --license                  Show license information.
  --desktopfile <file name>  The base file name of the desktop entry for this
                             application.
  -f, --fullscreen           Capture the entire desktop (default)
  -m, --current              Capture the current monitor
  -a, --activewindow         Capture the active window
  -u, --windowundercursor    Capture the window currently under the cursor,
                             including parents of pop-up menus
  -t, --transientonly        Capture the window currently under the cursor,
                             excluding parents of pop-up menus
  -r, --region               Capture a rectangular region of the screen
  -g, --gui                  Start in GUI mode (default)
  -b, --background           Take a screenshot and exit without showing the GUI
  -s, --dbus                 Start in DBus-Activation mode
  -n, --nonotify             In background mode, do not pop up a notification
                             when the screenshot is taken
  -o, --output <fileName>    In background mode, save image to specified file
  -d, --delay <delayMsec>    In background mode, delay before taking the shot
                             (in milliseconds)
  -w, --onclick              Wait for a click before taking screenshot.
                             Invalidates delay
```

Command:

```
spectacle -f -b -n -o "$HOME/Desktop/ScreenShot-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).jpg"
```

will capture the entire desktop image to the user Desktop folder aka desktop.

The command can be added to the KDE menu with the KDE menu editor: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html

[image]

The command can be launched with the user defined shortcut:

[image]

When the shortcut is clicked the picture is saved to the desktop:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. To make it even better, instead of `$HOME/Desktop` I would use `$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` (In my localized KUbuntu 20, the Desktop folder is not named "Desktop")

Answer (score 2):

ksnapshot is the KDE (kubuntu) version of screen capture. It can be launched from the menu or by pressing `prt scrn` button

Comment: but it seems it's not as simple as the OSX one (or even the XFCE one.) where a key combo will automatically result in screenshot in an accessible location. I don't want it to just launch the app, I want it to take a screenshot of the whole screen or a region of screen depending on the key combo used.

Comment: press "prt scrn"

Comment: `ksnapshot` has been deprecated. The application is now `spectacle`. See `spectacle --help`.

Comment: And for various reasons, I prefer `gnome-screenshot` which will need to be installed because it obviously isn't present by default.

Comment: yes gnome-screenshot is part of the gnome desktop not the KDE desktop. many gnome libraries will be installed with it

Comment: @ravery, surprisingly not! You can see what will be installed by running a simulation `apt-get install -s gnome-screenshot` if you're on Kubuntu 16.04. Alternatively, you can check the output of `apt depends gnome-screenshot` on any other flavor.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts**
2. Select Custom Shortcuts
3. Click **Add Custom Shortcut**
4. Fill fields

   - **Name** to `Take a screenshot of region`
   - **Command** to `spectacle -r`
5. Click OK
6. Double-Click one of the `unassigned` keyboard bindings
7. Insert your desired binding. (I'm using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Post configured]

You need to add in Global Shortcuts the Spectacle application. This applications has already a few shortcuts (the importante ones) pre configures but empty. Iǘe attached a picture of my configuration